# Is it possible to get historical weather data from HERE API for a specific date?

Tags: here-api, weather-api

I am looking to download the historical weather data for a location by sending a HERE API request containing a specific date.

The documentation here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/destination-weather/dev_guide/topics/overview.html is only about current weather data and I couldn't find any documentation about historical weather data for a specific date. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could try https://open-meteo.com/en/docs/historical-weather-api

With start and end date parameters you can specifically select one day.

Disclaimer: I am the author of open-meteo.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but you will need to contact one of our sales agents because this specific feature you are asking for is restricted to a different base plan:
https://www.here.com/pricing?form_id=2227&form_category=contact-us&cta_id=73306_contact-us&detailed_source=www.here.com%2Fpricing

You can always check our HERE Base Plan Pricing for more details.